# Server is down after updating httpd.conf

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

This is emergency.

I just want to do one stupid simple thing. I do not want to have dom logs. That's it.

So I edit vconf.local and rebuild httpd.conf.

Some error shows up like one domain has ownership conflict. So what? I just go ahead and restart apache

```
root@host [/var/cpanel/templates/apache2]# vi vhost.local
root@host [/var/cpanel/templates/apache2]# /usr/local/cpanel/bin/apache_conf_distiller --update
info [apache_conf_distiller] 'local' datastore in use (/var/cpanel/conf/apache/local)
info [apache_conf_distiller] Missing IP for domain host.buildingsuperteams.com, using 67.159.44.4
info [apache_conf_distiller] Missing port for domain host.buildingsuperteams.com, using 80
info [apache_conf_distiller] Missing user for domain host.buildingsuperteams.com, using nobody
info [apache_conf_distiller] Missing group for domain host.buildingsuperteams.com, using nobody
info [apache_conf_distiller] Missing ServerName for domain host.buildingsuperteams.com, using host.buildingsuperteams.com
info [apache_conf_distiller] Domain ownership conflict detected for buildingsuperteams.com, users nobody, building
Distilled successfully
root@host [/var/cpanel/templates/apache2]# /usr/local/cpanel/bin/build_apache_conf
info [build_apache_conf] 'local' datastore in use (/var/cpanel/conf/apache/local)
info [build_apache_conf] Missing IP for domain host.buildingsuperteams.com, using 67.159.44.4
info [build_apache_conf] Missing port for domain host.buildingsuperteams.com, using 80
info [build_apache_conf] Missing user for domain host.buildingsuperteams.com, using nobody
info [build_apache_conf] Missing group for domain host.buildingsuperteams.com, using nobody
info [build_apache_conf] Missing ServerName for domain host.buildingsuperteams.com, using host.buildingsuperteams.com
info [build_apache_conf] Domain ownership conflict detected for buildingsuperteams.com, users nobody, building
Built /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf OK
root@host [/var/cpanel/templates/apache2]# /etc/init.d/httpd -k graceful
root@host [/var/cpanel/templates/apache2]# service httpd status

Looking up localhost
Making HTTP connection to localhost
Sending HTTP request.
HTTP request sent; waiting for response.
Retrying as HTTP0 request.
Looking up localhost
Making HTTP connection to localhost
Alert!: Unable to connect to remote host.

lynx: Can't access startfile http://localhost/whm-server-status
root@host [/var/cpanel/templates/apache2]#
```

If I type service httpd restart it simply get out WITHOUT disclosing any error message

I check cpanel error log to no result

The ownership conflict happens most likely because the main domain is buildingsuperteams.com and yet I created another user to handle buildingsuperteams.com so I can change what's displayed when people access my IP

**Note:** While the comment is correct that the server works after doing service httpd start, the output strongly suggest that the httpd server has been online all along for 15 minutes. It's as if all I really needed to do is to actually just wait. There will be some follow up questions.

```
lynx: Can't access startfile http://localhost/whm-server-status
root@host [/var/cpanel/templates/apache2]# service httpd start
httpd (pid 2516) already running
root@host [/var/cpanel/templates/apache2]# service httpd status
                       Apache Server Status for localhost

   Server Version: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips
          mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635

   Server Built: Dec 20 2012 10:45:38
     __________________________________________________________________

   Current Time: Monday, 31-Dec-2012 22:08:15 CST
   Restart Time: Monday, 31-Dec-2012 21:52:58 CST
   Parent Server Generation: 3
   Server uptime: 15 minutes 16 seconds
```

Comment: `service httpd start` ? Doesn't look like you actually started apache.

Comment: It works. But how? Doesn't restart automatically start? Also why doesn't it happen automatically when I reboot server like usual? I guess you can turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
service httpd start
```

Doesn't look like you actually started apache.

It's possible the restart with `/etc/init.d/httpd -k graceful` command failed. Thus, there was no httpd service running. Or that the graceful was taking an extended period of time due to stalling process.

cpanel comes with various services that constantly checks whether an essential (as defined by cpanel) service is down or not and attempts to "automagically" restart that service. However, there is delay between when these checks are made. So, the start up procedure is not immediate.

When you boot the machine for the first time, it's not cpanel's checker that checks for their runtime but the OS's boot orders which include essential services.

For future reference, the command to restart (non graceful) is

```
service httpd restart
```

Additionally, you can view error_log at `/usr/local/apache/logs/error_log`

Comment: So service httpd restart doesn't start the service if it's not started in the first place?

Comment: @SeptiadiAgus `service httpd restart` is equivalent to `service httpd stop` followed by `service httpd start`. It will start the service if it wasn't running to begin with. But the first will fail.

Comment: I understand. So basically because service httpd stop fails it doesn't try the start part. Are you sure?

Comment: No, I just said it will still do the "start" even though "stop" will fail.

Comment: Which is what I expected. This is why I thought service httpd start is useless given that we have service httpd restart. The thing is I already did service httpd restart. I guess it simply takes a while for the restart to occur.